# Doctrine2 - using a foreign key column as a normal field

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, foreign-key-relationship

Is there a way to have something like this in doctrine:

```
class Entity {

    /**
     * @Column(name="related_entity_id")
     */
    private $relatedEntityId;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="RelatedEntitiy")
     * @JoinColumn(name="related_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    private $relatedEntity;
}
```

What I want to do I do something like this:

call Entity::setRelatedEntityId($someId), and persist the entity,
and have the entity return the related entity by calling Entity::getRelatedEntity().

The related entity is selected from a table which will be strictly limited and it will never dynamically grow at runtime, so there is a finite number of related entity ids.

At the time of creating a new Entity, I'd like to set the related entity id, but without having to fetch the whole related entity from the database.

As far as I could test this, it does not work, because if I set the relatedEntityId but not the relatedEntity, Doctrine automatically sets the related_entity_id column to null, since basically no relationship has been established.

I've tried to do something like this also:

remove the relatedEntityId property, and use

```
Entity::setRelatedEntity(new RelatedEntity($relEntId))
```

the constructor of the RelatedEntity will set the id, but not other values.
I do not want to persist the RelatedEntity (it's values are already set in the DB for the given $relEntId), but this time Doctrine signals an error at flush, because it has an unpersisted entity.

Basically, what I want to do is create a relationship without knowing anyhing but the Id of the related entity. If there is some other way this can be done, please share.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I've found a workaround. Since the RelatedEntities will be a limited set of immutable objects, I've done the following:

1. use the entityManager to find all RelatedEntities;
2. inject the list to the object that will be creating new Entities
3. when creating a new Entity, select one of the RelatedEntities from the list as its RelatedEntity

I'll leave the question open for a day or two, just in case somebody comes up with something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the entity proxy:

```
Entity::setRelatedEntity($entityManager->getReference('RelatedEntity', $relEntId))
```

Comment: The thing is, other domain objects will create new Entities, and I do not want to introduce the entity manager into the domain.

Comment: That's OK. His answer is still valid. When you use `getReference()`, you are getting an object of the same class as your entity. So you can use either the return value from `$em->getReference()`, or you can use an actual object created in your domain. Your domain does not need to know about Doctrine, and type hinting will still work.

Comment: @Pinetree you can always add another layer. Make an entity factory that will know about the EM and create your domain objects (and that is good OOP design).

Comment: @Meze, well right now I don't have time to do another redesign, and I've already dealt with it as described in the edit to the main post, but the factory approach seems ok if I come into the same situation in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is supposed to work like how you described :)

The entity you add must be a Doctrine managed object, so that means you have to load it yourself first using the `find()` family of methods.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'll leave this up for a while longer, maybe someone has some workaround or something...

Is there a way to stop doctrine being whiny about not persisting the entity maybe, like described in the second part?
This would have to be for this case only, I do not want to suppress all persistence errors.

Comment: @Pinetree please have a look at the answer from meze, it does exactly what you want, and it does not break the requirement of the domain not knowing about Doctrine. If you need more clarifications I'm sure one of us can help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Doctrine 2 further elaborated here http://ssmusoke.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/doctrine2-day-3-proxies-associations-relationships/

My approach is as follows:

a) Have only the $relatedEntity property

b) Add a getRelatedEntityId() function which returns the id value from $relatedEntity

c) Add a setRelatedEntityId() which sets the $relatedEntity object - you may need to load it from the database, saves you from polluting other layers when u only have the id of the related entity

d) Add getRelatedEntity() and setRelatedEntity() functions

BOTTOM LINE: You cannot have a property for the foreign key column and the mapped property as Doctrine gets confused

Comment: As I replied to meze, to have a setRelatedEntityId() work like that, I 'd have to inject the entityManager into the Entity, which I do not want to do.

Comment: I use a utility function loadEntity('ClassName', idvalue) which loads the entity manager from a singleton instance, loads an object of the specified class with the idvalue form the database and returns it.